# GraphDB Lucene connector: indexing rdfs:label values of a single language

Tags: lucene, graphdb

I'm going to pose a question about indexes in GraphDB Lucene connector.

In the context of a multilingual rdf resource, how is it possible to index the rdfs:label values of a single language (for example english) ?

I tried with this:

```
PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene/instance#>
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene#>

INSERT DATA {
     inst:lexicalEntryIndex :createConnector '''
 {
   "types": [
     "http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#LexicalEntry"
   ],
   "fields": [
     {
         "fieldName": "type",
         "propertyChain": [
           "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
           "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
         ],
         "languages": [
           "en"
         ]
     }
   ]
 }
 ''' .
 }
```

but **all** the languages are indexed.

Thanks in advance,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

The [GraphDB Lucene Connector documentation](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/lucene-graphdb-connector.html#indexing-language-tags) clearly demonstrates how to index a single language.

Here is a sample snippet how to do it:

```
PREFIX luc: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene#>
PREFIX luc-index: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene/instance#>

INSERT DATA {
  luc-index:my_index luc:createConnector '''
    {
      "types": ["http://www.ontotext.com/example#gadget"],
      "fields": [
         {
           "fieldName": "name",
           "propertyChain": [
             "http://www.ontotext.com/example#name"
           ]
         },
         {
           "fieldName": "nameLanguage",
           "propertyChain": [
             "http://www.ontotext.com/example#name",
             "lang()"
           ]
         }
      ], "entityFilter":"?nameLanguage in (\\"en\\")"
    }
  ''' .
}
```